# Spring ws XSD validation

Tags: spring-ws

Currently i am implementing web services using Spring-ws . Here i am struck with xsd validation . For xsd validation i am using the following configruation

```
    <bean id="validatingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="xsdSchema" ref="schema" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
      </bean>

<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/ProductSchema.xsd" />
  </bean>
```

Here i am passing the xsd file during bean initialization . Is there any way for me to send this(ProductSchema.xsd) xsd file dynamically. Because I will comes to know which xsd file needs to send based on the input payload.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many XSD's you have, but perhaps you can define imports in ProductSchema.xsd to include the others. That's at least how I've got it set up.

For example:

```
<import namespace="http://namespace" schemaLocation="data.xsd" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what you are trying to do.

But you can make different endpoints/methods that matches different payloads by annotating the handler method with a localPart that matches the name of an element i the payload:

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint {

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "NameOfMyXmlRequestElement")     
    @ResponsePayload
    public MyResponse handleMyRequest(@RequestPayload MyRequest MyRequest) throws Exception {
    ...
```

A recived request can then be unmarshalled/validated using a specific schema:

```
<bean id="myJaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>mydomain.model.oxm.MyRequest</value>
            <value>mydomain.model.oxm.MyResponse</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schema" ref="MyServiceSchema" />
</bean>

<bean id="MyServiceSchema" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="WEB-INF/schemas/MyService.xsd" />
</bean>
```

The MyRequest class must be annotated to work with the Jaxb2marshaller, @XmlRootElement(name="MyRequest") etc...